# How to create an email alert to task creator when task is complete

Tags: tasks, email-alert

Is it possible to create an email alert that goes to the task creator when a task is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with workflow rules but there are similar questions/answers found here, with alternative solutions... 
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gkeGAAQ
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gsHvAAI